# Testing power of a predictive model on a very granular data

Tags: dataset, prediction

I recently got a review and resubmit from a journal, with a comment that the predictive power of my model is weak. The reason why one of the reviewers said it was the fact that my MAPE for a holdout sample was 44%.

The nature of my data is high level of granularity.
I spoke with a practitioner who said that such MAPE is normal in his practice given how granular the data is (it is transaction-level data at store/week/product, and I am trying to predict which product attributes affect sales in general).

Given that the reviewers had no problems with my model in general, only with its predictive power described above, I am trying to build an argument that when you have data that is so diverse (across multiple physical stores and store chains in all 52 weeks) and also so granular, it is hard to obtain a a low MAPE.

Would you agree with it? If so, can you please point out to any white papers or academic papers that discuss such issue?

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you apply your estimated model to data aggregated at a higher level, can you get a substantially lower MAPE? Would that make it explicit what's going on?

Comment: Good question, I don't think I want to aggregate the data because what makes this data unique and valuable is its granularity of business transactions.

Comment: Unless this is your suggestion in order to tackle the reviewer's comment?

Comment: Are you having weekly data and then trying to predict one week ahead? Not entirely clear from your answer what is going on. Also, not clear how your hold-out sample was built. For instance, you could evaluate MAPE by using a rolling-window approach to predict weekly sales (which exploits the temporal correlation of your data).

Comment: I am not predicting into the future, meaning I don't treat the data as time series. Instead, I take the sample and randomly divide stores 70% vs 30 %. I use the estimates from the 70% of the stores  to predict Y (sales) of the 30% of stores. That is how I get the high MAPE.